# nodejs 'file-type' and 'mime': require() of ES Module is not supported; change index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in CommonJS modules

Tags: node.js, import, es6-modules, file-type

```
import mime from 'mime';
// import { mime } from 'mime'; // this is also tried

const determineFileType = async (filePath) => {
  const type = mime.getType(filePath);
  if (type) {
    logger.info(`File type is: ${type.mime} and the extension is: ${type.ext}`);
  } else {
    logger.info(`Could not determine the file type for ${filePath}`);
  }
  return type;
};
```

gives this error:

```
2024-Feb-18 09:11:29:1129 +0ms ip-172-31-47-89 pid:586768 error: uncaughtException: require() of ES Module /home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/mime/dist/src/index.js from /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/mime/dist/src/index.js from /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:851:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts:19:32)
    at m._compile (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:857:29)
(node:586768) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have also tried this code:

```
import { fileTypeFromFile } from 'file-type';

...
const type = await fileTypeFromFile(filePath);
...
```

which gives this error:

```
2024-Feb-18 09:14:12:1412 +0ms ip-172-31-47-89 pid:587367 error: uncaughtException: require() of ES Module /home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/file-type/index.js from /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/file-type/index.js from /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:851:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/my-app/src/utils/decompress.ts:19:21)
    at m._compile (/home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:857:29)
(node:587367) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

really confused here.

What is this error? I am having trouble finding a clue...

Comment: The error messages say it all. Your source code uses `import` but your project build is compiling to CJS, yet you are using ESM dependencies. To import ESM into a CJS context, you must use a dynamic `import()` to load the ES modules. So do `await import('mime')` and handle the associated promise accordingly in your control flow. That or you can convert your project's build to output ESM instead of CJS. Check this answer, it is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400071/cannot-require-import-while-creating-yeoman-generator/77417500#77417500